# Cannot set name of NFT in Elrond Rust testing framework

Tags: multiversx

I am writing tests for my smart contract using elrond-wasm 0.32.0.

My issue is that my smart contract returns the identifier of the ESDT token when I am getting the name.

### Detailed steps

I am setting my ESDT token's name like so:

```rust
    blockchain_wrapper.set_nft_balance_all_properties::<Empty>(
        &cf_wrapper.address_ref(),
        &ITEM_TO_EQUIP_ID,
        ITEM_TO_EQUIP_NONCE,
        &rust_biguint!(2u64),
        &Empty,
        0,
        Option::Some(&owner_address),
        Option::Some(ITEM_TO_EQUIP_NAME),
        Option::Some(b""),
        &[],
    );
```

Then, I get my ESDT token's name :

```rust
blockchain_wrapper
        .execute_query(&cf_wrapper, |sc| {
            let data = sc.blockchain().get_esdt_token_data(
                &ManagedAddress::from_address(&cf_wrapper.address_ref()),
                &TokenIdentifier::from_esdt_bytes(ITEM_TO_EQUIP_ID),
                ITEM_TO_EQUIP_NONCE,
            );

            // data.name equals ITEM_TO_EQUIP_ID, so it fail
            assert_eq!(data.name, ManagedBuffer::new_from_bytes(ITEM_TO_EQUIP_NAME));
        })
        .assert_ok();
```

Did I forget something, or is it a bug?

### Complete snippet

```rust
#[test]
fn set_name_test() {
    const WASM_PATH: &'static str = "sc-customize-nft/output/customize_nft.wasm";

    const ITEM_TO_EQUIP_ID: &[u8] = b"ITEM-a1a1a1";
    const ITEM_TO_EQUIP_NAME: &[u8] = b"item name";
    const ITEM_TO_EQUIP_NONCE: u64 = 1;

    let rust_zero = rust_biguint!(0u64);
    let mut blockchain_wrapper = BlockchainStateWrapper::new();
    let owner_address = blockchain_wrapper.create_user_account(&rust_zero);
    let cf_wrapper = blockchain_wrapper.create_sc_account(
        &rust_zero,
        Some(&owner_address),
        customize_nft::contract_obj,
        WASM_PATH,
    );

    // deploy contract
    blockchain_wrapper
        .execute_tx(&owner_address, &cf_wrapper, &rust_zero, |sc| {
            let result = sc.init(managed_token_id!(PENGUIN_TOKEN_ID));
            assert_eq!(result, SCResult::Ok(()));
        })
        .assert_ok();
    blockchain_wrapper.add_mandos_set_account(cf_wrapper.address_ref());

    blockchain_wrapper.set_nft_balance_all_properties::<Empty>(
        &cf_wrapper.address_ref(),
        &ITEM_TO_EQUIP_ID,
        ITEM_TO_EQUIP_NONCE,
        &rust_biguint!(2u64),
        &Empty,
        0,
        Option::Some(&owner_address),
        Option::Some(ITEM_TO_EQUIP_NAME),
        Option::Some(b""),
        &[],
    );

    blockchain_wrapper
        .execute_query(&cf_wrapper, |sc| {
            let data = sc.blockchain().get_esdt_token_data(
                &ManagedAddress::from_address(&cf_wrapper.address_ref()),
                &TokenIdentifier::from_esdt_bytes(ITEM_TO_EQUIP_ID),
                ITEM_TO_EQUIP_NONCE,
            );

            println!("Name is {:?}", data.name);
            assert_eq!(data.name, ManagedBuffer::new_from_bytes(ITEM_TO_EQUIP_NAME));
        })
        .assert_ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from an Elrond Developer:

> It's a bug in the mock. It's being set properly, but the get_esdt_token_data mock just returns the token ID instead of the name from metadata. Thanks for reporting!